# s3_website setting MIME type for files without extension using

Tags: amazon-s3, jekyll

I'm trying to deploy a Jekyll site. Here's the flow:

1. Content is added and pushed to BitBucket
2. BitBucket Pipelines builds the site
3. Finds all HTML files in `_site/` and removes their extension
4. Uses `s3_website push` ([s3_website](https://github.com/laurilehmijoki/s3_website)) to push contents to the designated S3 bucket

I'm removing the extension from the HTML files since I need clean URLs. Although, there's an additional step required to set the MIME type on these files to ensure S3 serves them correctly.

Somehow, the MIME type is being detected by itself as of now, and the site works, but I'm uncomfortable not having control over it. So, I tried to add the following to `s3_website.yml` to set the MIME type:

```
content_type:
  "*": text/html
```

But that breaks the site.

How do I set `s3_website` to pick only those files that do not have an extension, and set the MIME type only to them?

Answer (score 1):

The site would work without setting the MIME type, if Tika is able to correctly detect the content type by itself.

In case users need more control over this, the `s3_website` gem includes a [YAML configuration](https://github.com/laurilehmijoki/s3_website/pull/39) that can handle this version 1.15.0.

Add this to `s3_website.yml`:

```
extensionless_mime_type: text/html
```

This sets the MIME type for all files that don't have an extension, to text/html.